# push assoc array into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to assign object into an array within a loop?

My progress so far

```
item = [];

$.each(result, function(){
    //loop and assign array into an array
    //result is an object
    //result.a
    //result.b
});
```

Expected final result

```
item = [
    {'a': a},
    {'b': b },
    .....
]
```

Comment: What is in `result`, and how does that relate to what goes into `item`?

Comment: @Barmar result is an object. loop through it and assign every of its result.a and result.b into item array.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want an array like that. If each object has a different property, how will you access them?

Comment: @Barmar result.a will returned the value of 'a', and can't that be inserted into item[{'a':result.a}] ?

Comment: I mean how will you know what property to use when accessing `item[n]`? How do you know it's `item[0].a` and `item[1].b`?

Comment: @Barmar it's a must to specify key in $.each?

Comment: If you want to get the keys from the `result` object and use them in the new objects, yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var item = [];

$.each(result, function(key, value) {
    var newobj = {};
    newobj[key] = value;
    item.push(newobj);
}
```